# Adding time indication in Fullcalendar's Scheduler (resource view)

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

While using the Scheduler's Resource view the user found it hard to understand the hovering time.

Adding this below $('#calendar').fullCalendar( ... );

```
  $(".fc-slats tr").each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("timerow");
        });
```

and CSS

```
.timerow:hover {background: lightblue;}
```

PROBLEM: When user pressed next or prev buttons the calendar rendered again the table and the .hover did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding the code also in the viewRender in Calendar's properties solved it.

```
 viewRender: function (view, element) {
            $(".fc-slats tr").each(function () {
               $(this).addClass("timerow"); });
            },
```

The final result is shown in the image below:
[image]

[resource1](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/)
[resource2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128222/hover-effect-on-one-cell-of-agendaweek-fullcalendar)